# Use `dplyr` to avoid `for` loop: calculate distance to observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data sets `A` and `B` and for each observation in `A` I want to calculate a distance `distance` (e.g. an euclidean distance, L1 distance, or something else) to each observation in `B` (the calculation of the distance is based on the variables in the data sets). An observation from `A` should then be related to an observation in `B` for which this distance is minimal.

For example, if `A` has 5000 observations and `B` has 10000 observations then

```
for(i in 1:5000)
{
     x = data.frame(x = numeric(), y = numeric())

     for(j in 1:10000)
     {
         x[j,] = distance(A[i,], B[j,])
     }

     A[i,]$associated_row_B = x[which.min(x[1,]),1]
}
```

does basically what I want (I still have to solve if observations have the same distance). But since I am using `dplyr` I hardly ever had to use a for loop. My solution needs even two loops so I wonder if there is a possibility to avoid the for loop using a solution from `dplyr`/`tidyverse`.

A very basic example:

A:

```
i           a b
1 -0.5920377 a
2  0.4263199 b
3  0.6737029 a
4  1.3063658 c
5  0.1314103 d
```

B:

```
i           a b
1 -0.30201541 a
2 -0.07093386 b
3  0.96317764 c
4 -0.33303061 d
5 -1.00834895 d
```

and the distance function:

```
distance = function(x,y) return(c((x[2] - y[2])^2 + abs(x[3] - y[3]), y[1])
```

The first element of the return value is the actual distance, the second value is the identifier from B.

Comment: what libraries are you using? Where does distance come from?

Comment: and what distance? are we talking about geographical points... or x-y coordinates, or.. or... ? some sample data (use `dput`) would help.

Comment: I use `tidyverse`. `distance` is a actually a placeholder for some distance function like an Euclidean distance, L1 distance, a combination thereof, a discrete distance, ...

Comment: it will be better if you can provide 5, 10 rows from each data frame, provide the distance function. Provide a minimal reproducible example please.

Comment: The function `stats::dist` provides the distance between every pair of points in a matrix/frame, though with sizes like 5000 and 10000, that's likely very "expensive". Are you really trying to calculate 50 million distances?

Comment: even more than that.... 

I don't really know how to solve this without a for loop and I guess that a for loop makes that an even more tedious business.


I added an example which makes hopefully more clear what I want.


I don't even need a full working example, I am already thankful for some advice what functions could possibly help me solving this problem.

Comment: Using just dplyr, I think you can create a placeholder variable to cross join the two data frames (this is not efficient at all). Next you can compute the distance function to each row and finally group by each id and select the smallest distance value. HTH.


Why do you want to use dplyr? Using base function will give u a lot more flexibility and allow u to opmitize for complexity and memory usage

Comment: @PlamenPetrov well, so far dplyr offered me a huge toolbox of efficient data manipulation functions. Since I use dplyr, I almost never had to use a for loop so I thought that this issue could be also solved efficiently using some dplyr (or tidyverse) functions. I don't have to use it but as r2evans already hinted already using the standard functions is very expensive, I thought dplyr maybe offers some solution.

Comment: If you choose the strategy, I described above, the cross join will result in a 50M row df, which is pretty inefficient, in my opinion. If you go with loops and other basic functions you can implement a strategy so that you compute only distances between elements from the two df which are promising to produce min values. Depending on exactly what are you trying to do ( meaning if u apply a constraint like an element can be matched at most one or n times ), you can choose between a variety of such strategies or combinations of them. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair warning: this is going to be pretty inefficient for large datasets!

You can accomplish this using `crossing` from `tidyr` and `slice` from `dplyr`.

First, let's create two dummy dataframes, `A_df` and `B_df`

```
A_df <- data.frame(
  observation_A = runif(100),
  id_A = 1:100
)

B_df <- data.frame(
  observation_B = runif(50),
  id_B = 1:50
)
```

For clarity, I've kept the column names unique between `A_df` and `B_df`.  Next, we'll use `tidyr::crossing` to find every combination of rows between the two dataframes.  Next, we use `mutate` to calculate the distance (here I arbitrarily took the absolute value of their difference, but you can apply your custom distance function here).  Finally, we group by `id_A`, and keep only the minimum using `slice` (and base R `which.max`).

```
library(tidyverse)


full_df <- A_df %>% 
  crossing(B_df) %>% 
  mutate(distance = abs(observation_A-observation_B)) %>% 
  group_by(id_A) %>% 
  slice(which.min(distance))
```

Looking at `full_df`, we get what we were hoping for:

```
> full_df
# A tibble: 100 x 5
# Groups:   id_A [100]
   observation_A  id_A observation_B  id_B distance
           <dbl> <int>         <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
 1         0.826     1         0.851    44  0.0251 
 2         0.903     2         0.905     3  0.00176
 3         0.371     3         0.368    18  0.00305
 4         0.554     4         0.577    34  0.0232 
 5         0.656     5         0.654    10  0.00268
 6         0.120     6         0.110    37  0.0101 
 7         0.991     7         0.988     6  0.00244
 8         0.983     8         0.988     6  0.00483
 9         0.325     9         0.318    45  0.00649
10         0.860    10         0.864    40  0.00407
# ... with 90 more rows
```